# Talend: How to convert row into column

Tags: talend

I have all data are in one column with multiple rows. Each set of data starts with **Name** and ends with **Email**. I want to transform data from each row into multiple columns.

Data I have (each set of data are all in one column)

```
Name AAA
Factory Address: xxx
Tel: xxx
Fax: xxx
Office Address: xxx
Tel: xxx
Fax: xxx
Email: xxx
Name BBB
Factory Address: xxx
Tel: xxx
Fax: xxx
Office Address: xxx
Tel: xxx
Fax: xxx
Email: xxx
Name CCC
Factory Address: xxx
Tel: xxx
Fax: xxx
Office Address: xxx
Tel: xxx
Fax: xxx
Email: xxx
```

Is this possible to do with talend? and what operator should I be using to transform the data?

Data I have and what I want it to be:
[image: Data I have and what I want it to be]

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no delimiter in your input file to separate file to differentiate between two fields, you can define the schema of your input file in component "tFileInputPositional" . It might look like below screen shot

Input schema:
 [image: input schema]

In first row you can define the name of header of columns. Through above mapping you will get the values of particular field in alternative columns for e.g. "Name" literal will be available in "Column0" and it's value in "Column1". Map the values column to your output component, you can use "tFileOuputExcel" for this.

your job might look like this :

Sample job:
[image: sample job]

Let me know if you face any problem

Thanks